# TinyMCE and AJAX is not sending data to php in mysql server

Tags: php, html, sql, ajax, tinymce

> ```
>  <!-- Page containing form -->
> ```
>
> Paragraph
>
> ```
>        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
>
>
>
>         <script src="//tinymce.cachefly.net/4.2/tinymce.min.js"></script> 
>         <!-- Just be careful that you give correct path to your tinymce.min.js file, above is the default example -->
>         <script>tinymce.init({selector:'textarea'});</script>
>
>
>   </head>
> ```
>
> -->
>
> ```
>        <div class="container">  
>             <br />  
>             <br />  
>             <h2 align="center">Enter a new paragraph</h2>  
>               <div class="form-group">  
>                    <form name="add_paragraph" id="add_paragraph">  
>                         <div class="table-responsive">  
>                              <table class="table table-bordered
> ```
>
> id="dynamic_field">
>
> ```
>                                       <tr>
>                                         <textarea id = "paragraph" type="text" name="paragraph" placeholder="Enter paragraph text"></textarea>
>                                       </tr>
>                                       </tr>  
>
>                              </table>  
>                              <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit" />  
>                         </div>  
>                    </form>  
>               </div>
>        </div>
>   </body>    </html>    <script>    $(document).ready(function(){   
>   $('#submit').click(function(){            
>        $.ajax({  
>             url:"form1_support.php",  
>             method:"POST",  
>             data:$('#add_paragraph').serialize(),  
>             success:function(data)  
>             {  
>                  alert(data);  
>                  $('#add_paragraph')[0].reset();  
>             }  
>        });  
>   });    });   </script>
> ```
>
> require 'db/connect.php';
>
> $number = count($_POST["paragraph_name"]);  //it said experience
>   before, maybe experience_list?
>
> ```
> if($number > 0)    {
>   for($i=0; $i<$number; $i++)  
>   {  
>        if(trim($_POST["paragraph_name"] != ''))  
>        {  
>         $paragraph_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['paragraph_name']);
>         $paragraph_text = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['paragraph']);
>
>         $sql = "INSERT INTO paragraph (paragraph_name, paragraph_text) 
>                 VALUES( '$paragraph_name', '$paragraph_text')";  
>
>         mysqli_query($db, $sql);  
>        }  
>   }  
>   echo "Data Inserted";    }    else    {  
>   echo "Please Enter Your Paragraph.";    }    ?>
> ```

Comment: I'm a noob to this, maybe you can help me.  I'm doing traditional php/mysql data, and I'm having a hard time using MCE Editor.  It all looks fine on the page, but when I press submit, the "plain jane 'text'" field inserts while the data from the TinyMCE does not.  

I'm using an AJAX call to send data to the second page.  For whatever reason, it's not working.  Any help would be SO appreciated.

Comment: As a friendly recommendation ... you should look at the Stack Overflow guidelines on how to ask a good question.  Your question is not well organized and had I not worked for the company that make TinyMCE it would have been very hard to answer your question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: My apologies friend.   I didn't know the proper conduct.  Thank you for your response though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are replacing a `textarea` with TinyMCE then the actual `textarea` does not get updated automatically unless one of the following happens:

- You perform a standard HTML form submission - in this scenario TinyMCE will automatically update the `textarea` at the start of the form submission process.
- You use the `triggerSave()` API to force TinyMCE to update the `textarea`.

Try adding a `triggerSave()` call before you send the AJAX request.

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/api/tinymce/root_tinymce/#triggersave

Comment: Thank you.  The final code looks like this (re: the AJAX call).     <script> 
 $(document).ready(function(){   

      $('#submit').click(function(){  
          tinyMCE.triggerSave('paragraph');   
           $.ajax({  
                url:"form1_support.php",  
                method:"POST",  
                data:$('#add_paragraph').serialize(),
                success:function(data)  
                {  
                     alert(data); 
                     $('#add_paragraph')[0].reset(); 
                }  
           });  
      });  
 });  
</script>

Comment: If you have this fixed can you accept the answer provided so others know there is no need to provide further input?

Answer (score 0):

```
<textarea id="editor" name="editor" type="text"></textarea>

 tinyMCE.triggerSave();
    var content = $("textarea[name=editor]").val();
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("content", content);


 $.ajax({
            url: '../boot/newBlog.php',
            method: 'POST',
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(response) {
                switch (response){
                  
                }
              }
        });
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.